# Glassfish 4.1 gzip and cache problems

Tags: caching, glassfish, gzip

I have made the following changes in Configurations/server-config/Network config/Network listeners (and Protocols)/http-listener-1/

**HTTP tab**: Compression: ON, MIME Types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/javascript,application/json,text/xml,text/javascript, Minimum size: 1 B

**File Cache tab**: Status: Enabled, Max age: 6000 seconds (or even more)

Chome Developer Tools warns me about leverage browser caching (The following resources are missing a cache expiration... for all .css, .js, images, etc. files) and PageSpeed Insights tool warns me that compressing of all .js files (and images) is disabled (although I have set application/javascript and text/javascript in MIME types). It also warns me that all static resources (.css, .js, images, etc.) are missing a cache expiration like Chrome Developer Tools. I want to know what do I need to do to enable caching of static resources and to gzip all of the files with MIME Type that I have set.

Thank you.